# How to do COM dll reference counting the right way? Official Microsoft samples are inconsistent

Tags: c++, windows, dll, com, reference-counting

- Some implementations calls `DllAddRef()` and `DllRelease()` in the `CClassFactory` constructor, destructor, and `LockeServer` member function:
  https://github.com/microsoft/workbooks/blob/master/Clients/Xamarin.Interactive.Client.Windows.ShellExtension/ClassFactory.cpp
- Some do it only in `LockeServer`:
  https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/main/Samples/CredentialProvider/cpp/Dll.cpp
- And in others, the `CClassFactory` constructor and destructor use a totally different reference count variable from that of `LockeServer`:
  https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/main/Samples/NetworkAccessProtectionExtensions/cpp/SampleShvUi/shvuicf.cpp

Which one is the right way? Also the use of global reference count variables seems like a rather outdated pattern. Could static class member variables be used instead?

Comment: Most Microsoft samples don't use any framework nor tooling (by choice obviously) while in reality when you implement COM objects you typically rely on one like ATL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/active-template-library-atl-concepts WRL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/wrl/windows-runtime-cpp-template-library-wrl, C++/WinRT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/author-coclasses (not strictly limited to WinRT) which do the ground work for free.

Comment: The last example doesn't do DLL reference counting because it's not an in-process DLL server, it's an out-of-process EXE server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COM makes a distinction between DLL reference counting and object server reference counting.

Sometimes the object server is exactly one DLL and no more and it makes sense to combine them, sometimes the object server needs to maintain additional state (open files, network connections) and therefore requires different lifetime.

---

There's no disadvantage to using global variables for the `DllAddRef` and `DllRelease` reference counts -- those functions have to be global anyway so there's no possibility of having a class to store per-instance data.

And the globals will tend to be declared `static` in a single compilation unit -- that means no linkage and less work for the linker to do.  Since these functions are called via `LoadProcAddress` there's no lost opportunity for inlining them (inlining would require linkage so the variables can be found at all call sites).

In contrast, `CClassFactory` reference counts will tend to be stored in the `CClassFactory` class instance, which typically will be a singleton but there's no prohibition on advanced COM scenarios like tearoffs.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I still have trouble understanding why in my 2nd example, it only does reference counting in `LockServer`. Also some static code analyzers warn about globals, so I would like to avoid them if I could (trying to explain to auditors why some warnings are ignored is a pain). From your response, I guess static class member variables would also work?

Comment: @wmjdgla: I'm not sure why you think the credential DLL example only does reference counting in `LockServer`.  `LockServer` forwards to `DllAddRef` and `DllRelease`.  Ahh, you mean why the constructor and destructor don't also lock the DLL.  Well, they don't have to use the same shared reference count as `DllAddRef` and `DllRelease`, but they do have to influence the result of `DllCanUnloadNow`, so that example has a bug.

Comment: [MSDN says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-dllcanunloadnow) "A call to `DllCanUnloadNow` determines whether the DLL from which it is exported is still in use. A DLL is no longer in use when it is not managing any existing objects (the reference count on all of its objects is 0)" and that credential server completely fails to check whether there are living COM objects with non-zero reference count.

Comment: As far as static code analyzers, they should warn about globals with linkage, but not static file-scoped or namespace-scoped objects.